# What program to follow if I have a lifting competition in 4 week?

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, powerlifting, weighttraining

I am novice gym goer and even though my lifts are very beginning-intermidiate level,I am wondering what type of training should I do to prepare for the event.My weight is 62kg at 5'6" and my squat and bench are relatively weak compared to DL I think. Here's my numbers :
Back Squat 100kg.
DL 155kg.
Bench 75kg.

Comment: Edited,it's a squat,bench and DL comp.

Comment: Are the weights that you list you one rep maxes? Or do you lift those for multiple reps?

Comment: One rep,that's what I'd have to do in the event too.

Answer (score 2):

Four weeks is not a lot of time to prepare for a meet, but you can do some training to improve your performance.

First, don't worry about the differences in your lifts. Focus on making the biggest increases in weight that you can, without worrying which lifts the increases occur in. If you can add either 10kg to your deadlift or 2.5kg to your bench press, then adding 10kg will give you a better result in the competition.

Second, practice performing high intensity single reps. Add these to every workout. For example, if you would normally squat 3 sets of 5 at 80kg, instead, on your first workout, try adding a single at 90kg before your 3x5 sets. Then on your next workout, try a single at 95kg before your 3x5 sets. Keep increasing the weight on the singles workout by workout until they become difficult. And make sure you have safety bars set up in case you fail.

Third, practice your lifts in the same way that they will be performed in the competition. The most likely difference will be the bench press, where in powerlifting competitions you generally are required to wait for a command to begin, lower the bar to your chest and hold it still, wait for a command to press, and only then lift the bar. You need to get used to pausing at the bottom of the bench press like this, and if you have someone in your gym who can give you the commands while you lift, then that's even better.

Fourth, back off your training at least a few days before the competition. This is called a "deload" period and allows you to fully recover before the meet. A week would be normal, in which you might only do a low volume of training at your normal intensity, but since you only have a month to prepare, maybe you should reduce that to 4 days. For example, instead of a single rep at 95% of your one rep max and then 3x5 at 80%, you might do one rep at 90% and then one set of five at 80%.

Fifth, have a strategy for the meet. If it's run as a typical powerlifting meet, then you will have three attempts at each lift. A common strategy is to begin each of the three lifts with a weight that you could confidently lift for three reps. This is to ensure that you don't accidentally fail all three attempts, which would disqualify you from the competition. (Remember, if you miss an attempt, you can re-attempt with the same weight or heavier, but you can't request a lower weight.) Then on your second attempt, choose a weight that you are reasonably confident that you can lift for a single. Then if you succeed on that attempt, observe how difficult it was, and decide how much heavier you think you could go for your third attempt. E.g. You might choose 95kg for your first squat attempt, then 102.5kg for your second. If you get the 102.5 and it feels reasonably easy, you might try for 107.5kg on your final attempt, or if it felt difficult then only increase to 105kg for the third.